# setting "selected/active" row in datagrid when opening a form

Tags: datagridview, datagrid

I have a form that has a datagrid in it that contains a list of countries and their country codes. I want to be able to pass to this form a county code so when this form opens it highlights the passed country code/country, or if no country code is passed, the first country code/country is selected.

Comment: New day comes a new perspective. I am now searching through all the rows, and if I find a match, I am setting that row's selected property to true. That will make the "found" row the one that is highlighted. Now all I have to do is find a way to cause the datagrid to make this row "visible" on the screen. What I mean by visible is have this row appear on the screen when the form is initially opened.

Comment: I figured this out myself. Setting the CurrentCell to the row in question was the solution.